# Get items value from Dynamodb search result

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have to following code to query from dynamodb

```
Search search = table.Query(new QueryOperationConfig { Filter = filter, AttributesToGet = list of attributes});
```

I can see there is data in search by expanding its node while debugging, but could not find an easy way to get the items key and values directly.

I tried with

```
              List<Document> documentSet = new List<Document>();
 do
            {
                documentSet = search.GetNextSet();
               foreach (var document in documentSet)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(document["columnName"]);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(document["columnName"]);
            }
            } while (!search.IsDone);
```

Is there any direct way to get the keys and value from Search object in json or table any in any thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given an individual Document (in your case, the *document* object), you can call *document.ToJson()* or *document.ToJsonPretty()* to retrieve the JSON representation of the document. [This blog post](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx14U0PAQWWHGXM/) provides more details.